# Angular lost the most important thing, the binding?

Tags: angular, binding

I would like to know what happened with the binding of Angular that I thought was the most important, in the code below, if I modify the array item, there is no more bind and if I put `emails[i]` what I already think kinda ugly, the input loses focus with each digit. Thanks!

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let email of emails; let i = index; trackBy:trackByfn">
      <input [(ngModel)]="email">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span>{{ emails | json }}</span>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  emails: string[] = ['test@mail.com'];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert it to use ReactiveForms.

*template*

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li formArrayName="emails" *ngFor="let email of form.get('emails').controls; let i = index; trackBy:trackByfn">
        <input [formControl]="email">
      </li>
    </ul>
    <span>{{ form.value | json }}</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

*component*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form:FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    emails: this.fb.array(['test@mail.com'])
  });

  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) {

  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
}
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4qnhd).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. But I just think it's writing a lot for something that was so simple before. And not to mention that my code is actually not as simple as I posted to facilitate the answer. In my code Emails is just a property of a class that is already in a FormGroup.

Comment: You are semi right in that. It is a bit unfortunate that Arrays don't really work with template driven forms (which is what ngModel is part of). But considering that it is a good practice in general to seperate your model from your template, and the boilerplate is not that much, reactive forms are a good alternative. Especially when validation comes into play. For forms that don't need validation at all, it is a bit of overhead though.

Answer (score 0):

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

Now when you change the collection, Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the items that changed.